# TypeError: g.rangy.saveSelection is not a function using textangular + rangy + browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify, rangy, textangular

I am trying to implement `textAngular` into my `Angular.js` project that is packaged using `browserify`.

I installed `rangy` and `textAngular` via `npm`. They are included like this:

```
global.rangy = require('rangy');
require('angular-sanitize');
require('textangular');
```

When compiling the package with `browserify` via `gulp`, no errors are shown. However, as soon as I click on a button in the toolbar of the editor, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: g.rangy.saveSelection is not a function
    at Scope.m.startAction (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:38077:9364)
    at Scope.executeAction (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:38076:5862)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:18310:15), <anonymous>:4:230)
    at callback (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:28558:17)
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:20997:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:21097:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:28563:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:3252:214)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:3209:98)
```

I also tried to include the `saveSelection` function like this to no avail:

```
global.rangy.saveSelection = require('rangy/lib/rangy-selectionsaverestore');
```

It is the same error as this bug report, but for me it is still not fixed: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/853.

Help is appreciated, if more info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only include alex88s answer from Github:

```js
(() => {
  window.taTools = {};
  window.rangy = require('rangy/lib/rangy-core');
})();

require('rangy/lib/rangy-selectionsaverestore');
require('textangular/dist/textAngular-sanitize');
require('textAngular/dist/textAngularSetup');
require('textAngular/dist/textAngular');
```

https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/1056

However we are using **ES6** imports with **Babel**, and this is our working version as of `1.5.0` (both `angular` and `textAngular` versions are set to this).

```
import rangy from 'rangy/lib/rangy-core';

(() => {
  window.taTools = {};
  window.rangy = rangy;
})();

import 'rangy/lib/rangy-selectionsaverestore';
import 'textangular/dist/textAngular-sanitize';
import 'textAngular/dist/textAngularSetup';
import 'textAngular/dist/textAngular';
import 'textAngular/dist/textAngular.css';
```

However we truly think that this should be really simplified to just 2 lines (one is for loading the minified version and the other should be optional for the CSS).